MakieTeX fails to precompile
I made the huge mistake of updating a bunch of packages.
Now whenever I load in the MakieTeX package, I get the following error:
 Info: Precompiling MakieTeX [6d554a22-29e7-47bd-aee5-0c5f06619414]
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: `make_block_docstring` not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ C:\Users\User\.julia\packages\Makie\rEu75\src\makielayout\blocks.jl:114
 [2] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
   @ Base .\Base.jl:457
 [3] include(x::String)
   @ MakieTeX C:\Users\User\.julia\packages\MakieTeX\KAivD\src\MakieTeX.jl:1
 [4] top-level scope
   @ C:\Users\User\.julia\packages\MakieTeX\KAivD\src\MakieTeX.jl:35
 [5] include
   @ .\Base.jl:457 [inlined]
 [6] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt128}}, source::String)
   @ Base .\loading.jl:2010
 [7] top-level scope
   @ stdin:2
in expression starting at C:\Users\User\.julia\packages\MakieTeX\KAivD\src\layoutable.jl:5
in expression starting at C:\Users\User\.julia\packages\MakieTeX\KAivD\src\MakieTeX.jl:1
in expression starting at stdin:2


